# Create Function taking base class pointer but calling derived class function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes `A` (base) and `B` (deriving from `A`):

```
class A { };

class B : public A
{
    int data;
public:
    int get_data() { return data; }
};
```

Now I have a function test which takes base class pointer and calls derived class function :

```
void test(A * ptr)
{
    ptr->get_data();
}
```

But problem is `ptr` may point to `A`'s object or `B`'s object. If it points to `B`'s object, then OK, but if to `A`'s object, then it is a problem.

Moreover, I don't want to make `get_data()` virtual because `data` is not property of `A`'s object.

How can I check if `ptr` points to `B`'s object? One solution which I can think is `dynamic_cast` and check it for `NULL`.  Is it the best solution or can I have a better solution ?

Comment: The better solution is to declare `test` as `void test(B * ptr)`. Then it cannot be abused.

Comment: this code can't compile

Comment: dynamic_cast won't work unless you have at least one virtual function. But you seem reluctant to use the obvious solution. Could you explain why you don't want to use virtual? The reason you have given doesn't seem to be much of a reason.

Comment: @Kerrek :No, Actually test is a part of bigger function which takes A*. Moreover, it exactly not takes A*, instead it is a vector of A*'s, in which some point to A objects, some to B, so I can't actually change the interface.

Comment: Remember that in C++ you can overload functions, so you can have two functions with the same name but different arguments.

Comment: @john: If I use virtual, then I have to add get_data() into A class, but A object doesn't have data, so it doesn't make sense to create that function into A class.

Comment: @Heisenbug : Yes you are right, I have to have virtual function to work with dynamic_cast. so what should I do now?

Comment: @HappyMittal You could add a get_data that throws an exception. Or maybe there's some default value you could sensibly return. In any case you need a virtual function somewhere to use dynamic_cast. A virtual destructor would also be one option if you really don't want any other virtual functions.

Comment: Why don't you `try { } catch {  }` inside `test()` for the cases where  the elements are of type A; and then ignore the exception, since you know where it comes from.

Comment: @ilomambo: That doesn't even compile, I mean it says A class doesn't have get_data() method.

Comment: @HappyMittal According to the second comment, the code you posted doesn't compile either. Anyway, try to trick the compiler by casting ptr to (B*), and see if it compiles then.

Comment: Declare `get_data` as pure virtual in `A`. You don't have to provide an implementation of `A::get_data` but all derived classes will be required to. I assume your destructor is already virtual so the dispatch table is already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the interface of `A` and `B` (including adding virtual functions) and if you can re-shuffle the code in the `test` function you can use the "visitor pattern". Here's a sample using the better named `Base` and `Derived` classes:

```
class Visitor
{
public:
    void Visit(Base * B)
    {
    }

    void Visit(Derived * D)
    {
        int data = D->get_data();
    }
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Accept(Visitor * V )
    {
        V->Visit(this);
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    int get_data()
    {
        return data;
    }

    virtual void Accept(Visitor * V )
    {
        V->Visit(this);
    }
private:
    int data;
};
```

This way you can iterate over your vector of `Base*`, call `Accept` of each element and know that only for `Derived` elements the `get_data` method will be called.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I liked your solution most, so accepting it :D.

Comment: -1, this design creates a cyclic dependency between all 3 classes. Moreover, it will imply to repeat the same code within the `Accept` method of all derived classes.

Comment: @DocBrown How is `Base` dependent on `Derived`? As for repeating the code in `Accept`, this is how the Visitor pattern works in order to implement double dispatch.

Comment: Base depends on Visitor, Visitor depends on Derived, and Derived obviously on Base.

Answer (score 5):

This means your `test` function is lying. It is saying that it will accept a pointer to any `A` object, even types derived from `A`, but the function won't actually work for anything other than `B`. You're much better off taking a `B*`:

```
void test(B* ptr)
{
   ptr->get_data();
]
```

Comment: OK, actually I made my problem simpler to ask question which is costing me now :). Actually, test takes a vector of A*'s, now I have to call get_data only for those pointers which point to B object.

Comment: @HappyMittal: That doesn't make sense. If you want a vector of things that are the same, then they must have a common interface. Use a virtual function. There's no cost, since you already have a virtual destructor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance models the is-a relationship. Clearly in your code B is not an A and inheritance is the wrong model. You mention in your comment that you have a vector which is being passed to an enclosing, bigger, function. I would suggest that one of the following would be a better fit:

```
  1. std::vector<boost::any>
  2. std::vector<boost::variant<A,B>>
```

**Edit**
Here's an example using boost variant:

```
class A
{
public:
    void DoIt()
    {
        std::cout << "did it!" << "\n";
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void GetIt()
    {
        std::cout << "got it!" << "\n";
    }
};

typedef boost::variant<A,B> ab_t;
typedef std::vector<ab_t> list_ab;

void test(list_ab& list)
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(list), std::end(list), [](ab_t& item)
    {
        if(A* a = boost::get<A>(&item))
            a->DoIt();
        if(B* b = boost::get<B>(&item))
            b->GetIt();
    });
}
```

Comment: `B` is-a `A`, or at least it can be. It's just that `B` has an additional `data` field.

Comment: Why B is not an A. It has all properties of A (which I haven't written here to keep question short), along with extra data. For example : a football player is a player, but NUM_GOALS only is a property of football_player, not in general player.

Comment: @HappyMittal Okay, so why are you passing a vector of `Player*`s to a function that only works with `football_player*`s?

Comment: @sftrabbit: Actually I am not passing, I am kind of given the vector i.e. test is a big function which requires all player's info, along with some special info like total num of goals. Anyway, thanks for the informative reply.

Comment: "Clearly in your code B is not an A" - you cannot deduce the correctness (or incorrectness) of such a relationship from names like A and B. You need at least the full class names and the intended semantics.

Comment: I don't recall why I came to that fairly strong opinion. In retrospect I don't think my answer is very helpful. It is possible that I came to this conclusion because the OP wanted to use A and B polymorphically except that one of the key access functions (`get_data()`) was only modeled by B. I agree that additional class semantics are required to draw the conclusions that I did.

Answer (score -4):

You say that actually you have a vector of elements A or B, then your test function really looks like:

```
void test( A ** ptr )
```

Then you can use the overloading C++ capabilities to make a utility function, the right function will be called:

```
void test( A ** ptr ) {
    A * elem;
    int i=0;
    elem = ptr[i++];
    while(elem) {
        testElement(elem);
        elem = ptr[i++];
    }
}

void testElement( A * ptr ) { }
void testElement( B * ptr ) {
    ptr->get_data();
}
```

Comment: `testElement( B * ptr )` will never be called.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Why do you say that?, ptr should be polymorphic and the type of the element pointed by elem should be resolved at run time.

Comment: You are calling `testElement` and passing a variable of type `A*`. How exactly do you expect it to call `testElement(B*)`? You are relying on the variable type and signature of function to determine which one is called not the polymorphic behavior of `A` and `B`. That comes later inside of `testElement`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Isn't that what polymorphism is about? Having an array of `Animals`, but where each element can be a derived class `Lion`, `Monkey` or `Turtle`? So of course all elements are `A*`, but individual elements can be `B*`, which can only be know at runtime. Polymorphism does not mean all derived classes support the same set of methods (unless the methods are declared in the base class).

Comment: Your answer is **wrong**. When you call `testElement` (a _free function_) the compiler determines which version to use at _compile time_, **not** _runtime_. Since `elem` is declared as type `A*` the `testElement(B*)` version __never__ gets called. If instead you did `elem->get_data()` in the `while` loop **and** it was declared virtual in `A` then subtype polymorphism would be kick in. Run the code, it will **not** work like you are expecting.

Comment: @ilomambo read a book, please ([Inside the C++ Object Model](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545) if you want to get into the details, but any basic C++ book will do, too, to disabuse of your misconceptions)