# Common interface for all derived classes

Tags: c++

I have base class Item which store some data and grant access to it by accessors, like:

```
class Item{
  (...)
public:
  int get_value();
  double get_weight();
  ItemMaterial get_material();
  (...)
}
```

Then I've got derived classes like Weapon, Armor which add some additional data:

```
class Weapon : public Item {
(...)
public:
  int get_dmg();
  (...)
}
```

I store these Items in some container:

```
std::vector<Item*> inventory;
```

And here comes the problem with interface - how to get access to derived class data? I was thinking, and got 3 ideas:

**1. Separate interfaces**

Each derived class adds its data, like it is shown above, and then use dynamic_cast:

```
Item *item = new Weapon;
int dmg = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)->get_dmg();
```

**2. Common interface class**

Make an interface class with all accessors:

```
ItemInterface{
public:
  virtual int get_value() = 0;     //Item interface
  virtual double get_weight() = 0;
  (..)
  virtual int get_dmg() = 0;       //Weapon interface
  (...)
}
```

And then something like this:

```
Item : public ItemInterface{ (...) }
```

and

```
Weapon : public Item { (...) }
```

and finally we can access the data:

```
Item *item = new Weapon;
int dmg = item->get_dmg();
```

**3. Combination with templates and enums**

This idea is maybe a little weird :-) but:

implement enum with all item data:

```
enum class ItemData{
  Value,
  Weight,
  Material,  //Item data
  (...)
  Damage,    //Weapon data
  (...)
  Defense,   //armor data etc.
  (...)
  Null
}
```

and in base class some template function like this:

```
template<typename T>
T get_data(ItemData data){
  switch(data){
    case ItemData::Value: return _value; break;
    case ItemData::Damage: return _dmg; break;
    (...)
  }
}
```

and access data like:

```
Item *item = new Weapon;
ind dmg = item->get_data<int>(ItemData::Damage);
```

===

How do you think it should be done? I will be grateful for any advices!

Regards.

Comment: If you need to access specific derived-class stuff, why are you using pointers-to-base?  Put another way, given an arbitrary `Item*`, how will you know that it's suitable for converting to `Weapon*` in order to get the weapon-specific stuff?

Comment: None is good - if you can not model your data, use dynamic_cast

Comment: Because, for example, object Creature contains inventory, like shown in example, and I want to hold all Item-based classes in this container. If it is suitable? dynamic_cast is giving me this information. In other cases I think I should, for example, add some data field in the base class which is giving this information..

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: So 1st solution?

Comment: Look at the Visitor pattern for another option.

Comment: With questions like this, I always tell people they have to consider the code which will *use the objects* of the classes. Where will you use them, and what will be practical then? Other than that, your question is too broad. You have to test various different designs, see if they work, throw away those which would apparently complicate your code, and generally gain some years of experience with software-architecture design.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: though I can understand your POV, the described problem is a very common one among OO learners. Telling them "come back after some years when you got more experience" is not very constructive.

Comment: @DocBrown: I did not tell him to come back after some years. I told him that the question was too broad and that in order to find real answers, it would take him (like everyone else) some years. This was merely an invitation to ask more specific questions. I did answer such specific questions in the past (e.g. one which was like "is dynamic_cast always bad?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second and third option is obviously **not** the way to go - whenever you add a new type of item, you will also have to change the base class or the enum - that is definitely not what you want to if you need any basic form of maintainability in your code.

> And here comes the problem with interface - how to get access to derived class data

First you have to think of "where will your code do this"? Most of your code dealing with the whole `inventory` should only use the content as `Item*`, using only functions from the `Item` class.

If you have code specificially dealing with `Weapon` objects, the place where the `Weapon` objects are created (and inserted into the `inventory`), may also add them to another variable, maybe a weapons list in form of a

```
std::vector<Weapon*> weapons;
```

or to a member variable `Weapon*` of a class `Warrior` or something like that (but beware, you now will have two pointers to the same objects, so you have to think about ownership). So the code dealing only with weapons (for example, a member function of `Warrior`) does not access the `inventory` to get a `Weapon` object, it will always use the `Weapon*` directly.

If, for some reasons, you have to write some code which does something for all weapons from your inventory, then write a single function which extracts all `Weapon` objects using the `dynamic_cast` (or even better: make it an iterator function), and reuse this function whenever you need to get access to all weapons. So you don't clutter your code all over with dynamic casts, but keep this in just one place.

EDIT: another alternative (avoiding the dynmic cast) is using the visitor pattern, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120394/create-function-taking-base-class-pointer-but-calling-derived-class-function). But I don't really like the answer of that post, in the presented form it will imply a cyclic dependency "Base -> Visitor -> Derived -> Base", which is IMHO a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

```
ValueType Weapon::getProprtyValue( PropertyType id ) {
   switch( id ) {
      case kWeaponProperty01: return m_weaponProperty01;
      ...
      default: return Item::getPropertyValue( id );
   }
}
```

You can make some kind of universal accessor method, though it have some limitations, it could be quite handy, especially in case of content editors, serialization etc.

Comment: This is something like an EAV model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model, and it avoids the need for inheritance at all, which makes the question pointless. This *can* be a solution in some specific scenarios. But I don't question the correctness of the given inheritance tree of the OP, the question is valid for all kinds of class models where a vector of pointer-to-base class elements is given.